# How to compare numpy arrays of tuples?

Tags: numpy

Here's an MWE that illustrates the issue I have:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.full((3, 3), -1, dtype="i,i")

doesnt_work = arr == (-1, -1)

n_arr = np.full((3, 3), -1, dtype=int)

works = n_arr == 10
```

`arr` is supposed to be an array of tuples, but it doesn't behave as expected.

`works` is an array of booleans, as expected, but `doesnt_work` is `False`. Is there a way to get numpy to do elementwise comparisons on more complex types, or do I have to resort to list comprehension, flatten and reshape?

There's a second problem:

```
f = arr[(0, 0)] == (-1, -1)
```

`f` is `False`, because `arr[(0,0)]` is of type `numpy.void` rather than a tuple. So even if the componentwise comparison worked, it would give the wrong result. Is there a clever numpy way to do this or should I just resort to list comprehension?

Comment: Note that you could use Numpy views to transfrom a array view of a given type to another type so that the comparison works (as explained by the Simon's answer).

Comment: `numpy` uses `()` to indicate the `records` of a structured array, but this is to distinguish them from the `[]` used to mark dimensions.  So while `()` is used for input and display purposes, you have to use `arr[0,0].item()` to get an actual `tuple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems are actually the same problem! And are both related to the custom data type you created when you specified `dtype="i,i"`.

If you run `arr.dtype` you will get `dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])`. That is a 2 signed integers that are placed in one continuous block of memory. This is not a python tuple. Thus it is clear why the naive comparison fails, since `(-1,-1)` is a python tuple and is not represented in memory the same way that the numpy data type is.

However if you compare with `a_comp = np.array((-1,-1), dtype="i,i")` you get the exact behavior you are expecting!

You can read more about how the custom dtype stuff works on the numpy docs:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Oh and to address what `np.void` is: it comes from the idea that it is a *void c pointer* which essentially means that it is an address to a continuous block of memory of unspecified type. But, provided you (the programer) knows what is going to be stored in that memory (in this case two back to back integers) it's fine provided you are careful (compare with the same custom data type).